# R How to count cumulative time worked by working employees

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a simple table of the following example data.  The last cell for employee 9 is intentionally empty to indicate that the employee 9 is still working.

| employee ID | group | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | systems | 12-Jan-20 | 14-Feb-21 |
| 2 | biofx | 03-Mar-21 | 07-Sep-22 |
| 3 | systems | 03-Apr-21 | 06-Jun-22 |
| 4 | biofx | 01-May-21 | 07-Jun-22 |
| 5 | systems | 01-Oct-21 | 07-Jun-22 |
| 6 | biofx | 01-Dec-21 | 01-Sep-22 |
| 7 | systems | 01-Jan-22 | 01-Oct-22 |
| 8 | biofx | 01-Feb-22 | 01-Nov-22 |
| 9 | systems | 01-Jun-22 |  |

what I would like to calculate and plot is for each day in a range, how many cumulative workdays have been worked by the currently working employees.    If I can get that far, I plan to show an area plot colored by group, or something similar.  The hope is that this analysis will highlight the dates when the most senior employees left the company.

So far I have imported and lubridated my table:

```
#loads the table above with NA in the empty cell
DATES = read_excel(fname)

#example date range. Will likely use the minimum start date eventually
date_range = as_date(mdy("1-1-20"):mdy("1-1-23"))

#reformat the date columns and create an interval
DATES = DATES %>%
  mutate(start_date_ymd = ymd(start_date)) %>%
  mutate(end_date_ymd = ymd(end_date)) %>%
  select(-start_date, -end_date) %>%
  mutate(work_interval = interval(start_date_ymd, end_date_ymd)) 

# naive start - can I just plot the number of workers working on each day?
num_workers<- sapply(date_range, function(x) sum(x %within% DATES$work_interval))
tibble(date_range, num_workers) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date_range, y=num_workers)) +
    geom_point()
```

Although the last couple of lines above aren't quite what I want -  Why don't I see data for worker 8 working up to november?

[image]

But even when I figure out why my plot is wrong, I'm really needing some direction about how to calculate on each day the sum of the days worked for all employees working that day.

Comment: Probably doable with a nested loop where the outer loop goes over every day (d) in the range and the inner loop loops over intervals that intersect with d and adds up everything the intersecting intervals have before d.  There's got to be a way to do it without loops though?

Comment: Fixed my plot by:
1: using `int_overlaps` instead of `%within%`
2: ordering the params so that I get a list the length of the working intervals to `sum` to get the count of overlaps. `sapply(R$query_dates, function(x) sum(int_overlaps(DATES$work_interval, x)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the list of all days between start and end.  Then summarize by date.

```
# Basic dataset.  Fill in missing end date.
df <- read_table("employee_ID   group   start_date  end_date
1   systems 12-Jan-20   14-Feb-21
2   biofx   03-Mar-21   07-Sep-22
3   systems 03-Apr-21   06-Jun-22
4   biofx   01-May-21   07-Jun-22
5   systems 01-Oct-21   07-Jun-22
6   biofx   01-Dec-21   01-Sep-22
7   systems 01-Jan-22   01-Oct-22
8   biofx   01-Feb-22   01-Nov-22
9   systems 01-Jun-22   ") %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with("date"), lubridate::dmy)) %>% 
    replace_na(list(end_date =lubridate::today()))

# Expand by date:
df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(days = map2(start_date, end_date, ~seq(1L, as.integer(.y - .x), by = 1L))) %>% 
    unnest(days) %>% 
    mutate(date = start_date + lubridate::days(days)) %>% 
    select(-start_date, -end_date)

# Summarize by date:
df3 <- df2 %>% 
    group_by(date, group) %>% 
    summarize(num_workers = n(),
              total_experience = sum(days))

# Plot cumulative days worked
df3 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, total_experience, fill = group)) +
    geom_col()
```

You can clearly see the days when people leave, and how much experience they took with them.